# Use group by on a group by result in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a NodeJS and a Mongoose Project and I have the following two schemas.

**UserSchema.js**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  incharge: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Adhihariharan', 'Anuja', 'Dhivya', 'Govind', 'Joann'],
    required: true
  },
)}
```

**ContactSchema.js**

```
const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add a name'],
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        'Not Called',
        'Wrong Number',
        'Called/Declined',
        'Called/Not Reachable',
        'Called/Postponed',
        'Called/Accepted',
        'Emailed/Awaiting Response',
        'Emailed/Declined',
        'Emailed/Confirmed',
      ],
      default: 'Not Called',
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
```

I am looking for a query which would give me a result which looks as the following:

```
[
  {
    _id: "5d7a514b5d2c12c7449be048",
    name: "Benita",
    incharge: "Joann",
    statuses: [
          { status: "Not Called", count: 1 },
          { status: "Called/Accepted", count: 1 },
          { status: "Called/Declined", count: 1 },
          { status: "Called/Not Reachable", count: 1 },
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5d7a514b5d2c12c7449be048",
    name: "Febia",
    incharge: "Dhivya",
    statuses: [
          { "Not Called": 2 },
          { "Called/Postponed": 2 },
          { "Called/Declined": 3 },
          { "Called/Not Reachable": 1 },
    ]
  },

  ... and so on
]
```

Here, the integer, is the number of times that status appears for a particular user and in charge is the manager in charge of the user. The `_id` mentioned is the ID of the user.

The `_id`, user, in charge belong to the UserSchema and the status belongs to the ContactSchema

I have tried the following query:

```
teams = await Contact.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { user: '$user', status: '$status' },
          count: { $sum: '$count' },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'members',
          localField: '_id.user',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'user',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: { path: '$user' },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          'user.name': 1,
          'user.incharge': 1,
          count: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { 'user.incharge': 1, 'user.name': 1 },
      },
    ]);
```

And the following was the output:

```
{
    _id: { user: 5ff52b10fa237b001c93ef18, status: 'Not Called' },
    count: 1,
    user: { name: 'Benita', incharge: 'Joann' }
  },
  {
    _id: { user: 5ff4ca05fa237b001c93ef15, status: 'Not Called' },
    count: 2,
    user: { name: 'Febia', incharge: 'Dhivya' }
  },
  {
    _id: { user: 5ff4ca05fa237b001c93ef15, status: 'Called/Accepted' },
    count: 4,
    user: { name: 'Febia', incharge: 'Dhivya' }
  }
```

Can someone please help me get the desired result?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I did try @turivishal's approach but this is what I got:-

```
{
    _id: 5ff52b10fa237b001c93ef18,
    name: 'Sadana',
    incharge: 'Joann',
    statuses: [ [Object] ]
},
{
    _id: 5ff4ca05fa237b001c93ef15,
    name: 'Sudarshan B',
    incharge: 'Joann',
    statuses: [ [Object], [Object] ]
}
```

Can you please tell me how I can access the [Object] inside the status array in mongoose so that I can get a result as below...

```
{
    _id: "5ff4ca05fa237b001c93ef15",
    name: "Sudarshan B",
    incharge: "Joann",
    statuses: [
          { "Not Called": 2 },
          { "Called/Postponed": 2 },
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [lookup with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `$lookup` with contact pass `_id` in `let`,
- `$match` user id condition
- `$group` by `status` and get total count
- `$project` to change name of the key and value
- `$addFields` to convert `statuses` array to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
teams = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "contact",
      let: { user: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$user", "$user"] } } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$status",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$count"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "statuses"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { statuses: { $arrayToObject: "$statuses" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cl1C5ECIj0q)